# How do you get an iPhone's device name

Tags: ios, uikit

If you open `Settings -> General -> About`, it'll say **Bob's iPhone** at the top of the screen.  How do you programmatically grab that name?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

From the **`UIDevice`** class:

**Swift version:**

`UIDevice.current.name`

**Objective-C version:**

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];`

> The UIDevice is a class that provides
> information about the iPhone or iPod
> Touch device.
>
> Some of the information provided by
> UIDevice is static, such as device
> name or system version.

source: http://servin.com/iphone/uidevice/iPhone-UIDevice.html

**Offical Documentation:** [Apple Developer Documentation > `UIDevice` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice?language=objc)

Comment: Be careful: the tutorial at that link, while quite useful, is aimed at OS 2.2, and uses some methods that are deprecated in 3.0.

Comment: @Tim: You are absolutely right. I didn't think of that. Though, I wasn't suggesting the tutorial; I was simply providing my source of information plus a source for more information.

Comment: @FrankV What permissions should I request from the user in order to get myMusicAppName to change his Iphone name? How do I do that in Swift? Thank you

Answer (score 182):

In addition to the above answer, this is the actual code:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];`

Answer (score 110):

Remember:  `import UIKit`

Swift:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().name
```

Swift 3, 4, 5:

```
UIDevice.current.name
```

Comment: Must have import UIKit

Comment: swift 5.1: UIDevice.current.name

Comment: Yes, UIDevice.current.name worked for me in Swift 5. Similarly I can tap into .model .batteryLevel etc Thanks!

Comment: UIDevice.current.name its not work under iOS16 (beta3)

Answer (score 15):

Here is class structure of UIDevice

```
+ (UIDevice *)currentDevice;

@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *name;              // e.g. "My iPhone"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *model;             // e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *localizedModel;    // localized version of model
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *systemName;        // e.g. @"iOS"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *systemVersion;
```

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately from iOS 16 onwards you need a special entitlement. You can request it here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/user-assigned-device-name/
[image: i]

Answer (score 10):

For swift4.0 and above used below code:

```
    let udid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
    let name = UIDevice.current.name
    let version = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
    let modelName = UIDevice.current.model
    let osName = UIDevice.current.systemName
    let localized = UIDevice.current.localizedModel
    
    print(udid ?? "") // ABCDEF01-0123-ABCD-0123-ABCDEF012345
    print(name)       // Name's iPhone
    print(version)    // 14.5
    print(modelName)  // iPhone
    print(osName)     // iOS
    print(localized)  // iPhone
```

Comment: this is great. so helful.

Comment: UIDevice.current.name its not work under iOS16 (beta3), Apple changed again.

Answer (score 6):

For xamarin user, use this

```
UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Name
```

Comment: Thank you. 
For Swift 3 : 

UIDevice.current.name

Answer (score 6):

*For Swift 4+ versions,* please use the below code:

```swift
UIDevice.current.name
```

Answer (score 4):

To get an iPhone's device name programmatically

```
 UIDevice *deviceInfo = [UIDevice currentDevice];

 NSLog(@"Device name:  %@", deviceInfo.name);
```

> `// Device name:  my iPod`

Answer (score 4):

Device Name would not work out of Box now, Need to have a special entitlement.

**Entitlement :**
com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name

**Doc :** https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708275

**Official :** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, using C#:

```
SystemInfo.deviceName;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 16 `name` cannot be used for that and unfortunately I couldn't find an alternative. From `UIKit.UIDevice`:

```
open var name: String { get } // Synonym for model. Prior to iOS 16, user-assigned device name (e.g. @"My iPhone").
```