# How to obtain iOS Device name

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I programmatically obtain the Device name of the iOS device
i.e. "Bob's iPad". This name is visible in the Settings > General > About > Name

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7919089/1677480

Comment: This question is for a different one of "Bob's" devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the device name with:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

:)