# How can I get the device name from UIDevice with React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want access to the device name (from UIDevice) with React Native. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Show this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100127/how-do-you-get-an-iphones-device-name

Comment: I understand it's accessible from UIDevice, I'm wondering if there's a React Native library or way to expose UIDevice.

Comment: NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);

Comment: Your comment is unhelpful because it ignores the React Native part of the question.

Comment: Here is a component the gives some info about the device, you could extend it https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-native-device or build your own one native component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a [Native Modules (iOS)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content). Here are the steps:

- Make native iOS component for getting device name
- Use it in JS

**1.** Make Component

```
//  Device.h
@import UIKit;
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface Device : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end

//  Device.m
#import "Device.h"

@implementation Device
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(deviceName:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
  callback(@[deviceName]);
}
@end
```

**2.** Use it in JS

```
var Device = require('react-native').NativeModules.Device;
Device.deviceName( (name) => {
  console.log(name) 
});
```

Comment: Device is undefined in JS and i get this error: `Cannot read property 'deviceName' of undefined`