# How to change the iPhone device name programmatically using Private frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I want to change the name of iPhone device.

App is for enterprise distribution, so I can use private frameworks.

Comment: I think you can't change iPhone device name by coding but if you want to get name of your device then you do it by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100127/how-do-you-get-an-iphones-device-name

Comment: Thanks, that I know, But I want to change device name